# Test that instance method calls class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Simply put, I have a class with an instance method which calls a class method, and I want to test using RSpec that the class method is being called when I run the instance method. So, for example

```
class Test
  def self.class_method
    #do something
  end

  def instance_method
    #do stuff
    self.class.class_method
  end
end
```

In RSpec, I've tried Test.should_receive(:class_method), but that seems to do something weird causing my tests to return weird behavior. If that is what I'm supposed to be using, maybe RSpec is out of date? I'm using RSpec 2.7.0. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant part of (or all of) your rspec test code, otherwise it will be impossible to debug what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really care *what* the class method is doing, and only that it gets called, you can do something like:

```
describe Test do
  context '#instance_method' do
    it 'should call the class method' do
      Test.should_receive(:class_method)
      Test.new.instance_method
    end
  end
end
```